# How to adjust the size of components inside a GUI proportional to the master frame size in Python using Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a GUI with several buttons, text boxes,... in Python using TKinter. At this moment, all sizes of the components are fixed, so whenever the main frame is resized, the components do not adjust to the size of the main frame. As a result, when the frame reaches a certain size, components disappear.

Is there an easy solution that makes the sizes of the components dynamic and proportional to the size of the main frame?

The pictures below speak for themselfs...

Thanks in advance!

[image: full screen]

[image: Resized]

Comment: Which geometry manager are you using?

Comment: I am using the place manager.

Comment: did you have a look at [`grid`](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html)?

Comment: I did, however, I was recommended to use place(). But I will have a look at it right away!

Comment: The simple answer is "don't use `place`".